# What does "wedge" mean, as in "wedge" a head of Cabbage?

Tags: beef, slow-cooking, food-processing, cabbage

In a recipe on Corned Beef and Cabbage, the instructions read "wedge" the head of cabbage before putting it in the slow cooker.

Comment: [Wedge (Geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_(geometry))

Answer (score 16):

Another way to say this is to *quarter* the cabbage. The goal is to make "wedges" (triangles, when viewed from above) that are smaller than an entire head of cabbage (easier to cook and fit in your slow cooker) but still relatively intact.

To wedge a cabbage, slice it in half, and then slice the halves into either 2 or 4 pieces (depending on how large a wedge you want).

[image: wedges of cabbage]
*Image from [Green Lite Bites](http://greenlitebites.com/2010/06/roasted-grilled-cabbage/)*

Comment: Are you supposed to core the cabbage?

Comment: I would. Once it's in quarters (as pictured) just cut diagonally along the core.

Comment: Not strictly necessary, but the dense chunk at the bottom isn't beloved by everyone.